# Fixed multiple div tags not overlapping

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following block of code:

```
<div class="fixme">Fixed 1</div>
<div class="fixme">Fixed 2</div>
<div class="fixme">Fixed 3</div>
<div class="fixme">Fixed 4</div>
```

And css:

```
.fixme {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 24%; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 2%; 
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:red;
}
```

I want each block as below:

[image]

But as a result, my blocks are overlapped and not separated as I want

http://jsfiddle.net/uacqjs91/

Comment: Of course, because You use `position:fixed` and `bottom:0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your tag divs, And add the position css to the wrapper

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 24%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixme {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.fixme:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixme">Fixed 1</div>
  <div class="fixme">Fixed 2</div>
  <div class="fixme">Fixed 3</div>
  <div class="fixme">Fixed 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your items and then only set the fixed position to the wrapper like so:

```css
.fixme {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixme .item {
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
}

body {
  font: .8rem/1.2 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixme">
  <div class="item">Fixed 1</div>
  <div class="item">Fixed 2</div>
  <div class="item">Fixed 3</div>
  <div class="item">Fixed 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are using the same class for all items.

Set `.fixme` as an overall div and mention the all four items as its child element `.fix`

```css
.fixme {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 24%; 
  
}
.fixme .fix {
   margin-bottom:20px; 
   padding: 2%; 
   background-color:red; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="fixme">
<div class="fix">Fixed 1</div>
<div class="fix">Fixed 1</div>
<div class="fix">Fixed 1</div>
<div class="fix">Fixed 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have a nice day